# Laptop with internal serial port in 2009 (and 2010)

Tags: laptop, serial-port, serial, rs232

Are there any computer vendors (like Dell, Lenovo, or..) that still sell laptops with an internal serial port?

We are using several modem and other kind of *box* at work that have to be used (and/or programmed) with serial port (RS232, DB9, ..). We tried many usb/pcmcia serial adapter which run fine when used to load programs on the *boxes* but not with modems. The protocol behind the RTC connection (with modem) need timer we are not able to reach when using an adapter (maybe until we find a very good adapter), and that leads to my question..

Comment: Have you tried Ethernet to serial port?  Moxa makes many such devices (http://bit.ly/7hO0BL).

Comment: If you have a good quality buffered USB to serial adapter, they will work in many (but not all) cases that the cheapies fail.  Lack of real hardware serial ports on new machines forces me to keep laptops in service that I'd prefer to retire.  :-(

Comment: You can buy USB dial-up modems, which may eliminate your modem problems.  Alternatively, you can by PCI Serial I/O cards for any desktop computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My brand new Dell Latitude E5500 has a serial port on the left side of it.  Alas, it has no parallel port.

[image: Latitude E5500 serial port detail]

Comment: Dell Product Page: http://www.dell.com/us/en/enterprise/notebooks/laptop_latitude_e5500/pd.aspx?refid=laptop_latitude_e5500&cs=555&s=biz

Comment: I've look around and.. well it seems this is one of the very last laptop that have this port..

Answer (score 1):

Panasonic and Fujitsu have them in nice laptops.

Comment: @Gnoupi: More like "decrapified".

Answer (score 1):

I have also just started looking for a new laptop with a serial port.

I can confirm eleven81's answer that Dell is still selling the Latitude E5500, however that machine is limited to Core 2 Duo processors.  If you go to the newer E6410 and E6510 you gain access to i5 and i7 processors, but they have dropped the serial port.

In following Tim's answer, the Fujitsu Lifebook E780 also has a serial port, but also comes with i5 and i7 processors - albeit at several hundred $$ more than the E5500's.

The Panasonic Toughbook series all seem to have serial ports, but with different processors.  The 52 has Core 2 Duo or Core i5 processor.  The 19, 30 and 74 have Core 2 Duo.  And the base price of the Toughbooks also seems above the other two vendors top prices.

Answer (score 0):

The e-series of Dells have a legacy port (serial/parallel) adapter available, and the elite docking station offers serial + parallel as well.

Answer (score 0):

HP just release a nice Notebook with serial port and the option to use an i5 or i7 processor.  It's the HP Probook 6540b Notebook PC.  I just bought one for much cheaper than the Fujitsu and the Panasonic and it has a lot of the perks/options you could want.  Julia at customer service did a great job hooking me up with the best possible configuration (and also threw in a nice discount)....    Call her (800) 888.5858 ext. 7719068.  She definately knows her stuff!!  Here's what I got with it...

```
Configurable - HP Probook 6540b Notebook PC
(ENERGY STAR)
NF162AV
HP Probook 6540b Notebook PC with ATI Radeon HD 4550 512MB Discrete Graphics
Genuine Windows® 7 Professional 64 (MS Office Trial not included)
Genuine Windows 7 Logo
Intel Core i7-620M Processor (2.66GHz, 1066, 4MB L2 cache)
Intel Core i7 Label
Estar Label
Webcam Integrated 2.0MP Only Available with and required selection for Display w/Camera
15.6-inch diagonal HD+ LED anti-glare (1600 x 900) WVA WWAN and Camera
ATI RadeonT HD 4550 512MB Discrete Graphics
4096MB (1333-MHz, DDR3, 2DIMM) - 64-bit OS recommended with 4GB memory
500-GB SATA Hard Drive (7200 RPM)
DVD+/-RW SuperMulti with Double Layer LightScribe Drive
Dualpoint Keyboard US (touchpad and pointstick)
802.11b/g/n Wi-Fi Adapter US (Intel)
HP Integrated Module with Bluetooth® 2.1 Wireless Technology
HP Mobile Broadband (powered by GobiT) with GPS
Service Provider Verizon Wireless, Sprint or ATT
56K v.92 high speed modem
Integrated Fingerprint Reader
Integrated Smart Card Reader
HW Ki t 90W US
9-cell (93 WHr) Lithium-Ion primary battery
```

Answer (score 0):

All Toshiba Tecra A11 and Tecra S11 models come with a built in serial port.

Panasonic Toughbooks as well.

Comment: I don’t know if *all* is the appropriate term since Panasonic seems to still be using the Toughbooks label, and I highly doubt they include one in any made in the last several years.